# Why is my upvote not considered properly in reddit?

Tags: reddit

Yesterday I upvoted one comment, immediately I logged off. My upvote is gone.

If I login again it is showing again my upvote.

I saw other person's comment karma there is no change in it for my upvote.

I asked them (moderators) they reply me: **Upvotes: karma is not a 1:1 ratio.** Which I didn't quite understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of Reddit's Vote Fuzzing. The upvotes and downvotes shown are not the actual amount of votes. From the [Reddit FAQ:](https://www.reddit.com/wiki/faq)

> #### How is a submission's score determined?
>
> A submission's score is simply the number of upvotes minus the number
> of downvotes. If five users like the submission and three users don't
> it will have a score of 2. Please note that the vote numbers are not
> "real" numbers, they have been "fuzzed" to prevent spam bots etc. So
> taking the above example, if five users upvoted the submission, and
> three users downvote it, the upvote/downvote numbers may say 23
> upvotes and 21 downvotes, or 12 upvotes, and 10 downvotes. The points
> score is correct, but the vote totals are "fuzzed".
>
> #### How is a comment's score determined?
>
> According to the same principles as a submission's score.
>
> A comment's score is simply the number of upvotes minus the number of
> downvotes. If five users like the comment and three users don't it
> will have a score of 2. Please note that the vote numbers are not
> "real" numbers, they have been "fuzzed" to prevent spam bots etc. So
> taking the above example, if five users upvoted the comment, and three
> users downvote it, the upvote/downvote numbers may say 23 upvotes and
> 21 downvotes, or 12 upvotes, and 10 downvotes. The points score is
> correct, but the vote totals are "fuzzed".